# Using bootstrap for commerical site?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website using django and since im not that strong in html/css (i can code and create layouts, but not the ones that look professional enough) i thought i might use the Bootstrap open source product, originally created by twitter.

Bootstrap is using the Apache License 2.0 as far as i can see and when reading it there does not seem to be any problems using it for commerical perposes...but i still wanted to ask since reading terms and condition isnt something i do every day and im not a lawyer.. can i use  bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) for commercial websites ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tonnes of sites use it every day, and many of them for commercial purposes. Feel free to use bootstrap for any use you please.

Comment: thanks for your fast replies, then it think that would be the way to go, i like the lightweight and responsive feel it has, not cluttered by a lot of images, slideshows and whatnot..i prefer a very fast user experience compared to that

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check the comparison between various licenses here http://choosealicense.com/licenses/. And using twitter-bootstrap is absolutely fine for a commercial website. You can check few websites using bootstrap here in the expo http://expo.getbootstrap.com/